# How can i hard-wire a link, in blocks, using $base_url or something similar?

Tags: blocks

I'm trying, unsuccessfully so far, to create a block that is simple hard-wired link. but i need to use $base_url or something equivalent (like base_url(); ?) but i guess adding php is not allowed.

i tried a few different things in the block body. for example…

```
<a href="<?php print $base_url . '/archive/program-archive-2012--2013' ?>"> Archives</a>
```

how i can achieve this, without using a full, or literal URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard wired to what?

Personally I like to hard wire my URLs the the root of the site. If my site is always a full domain name as `wwww.mysite.com` The url would be:

```
<a href='/archive/program-archive-2012--2013'> Archives</a>
```

This is relative to the root of the website. Which makes sense to me. You can move your site to a new domain, `www.mysite2.com`, and this *Path* will still work.

If you move your site to a sub-directory later then .htacess `BaseRewrite` rules can still allow this to work.

I find trying to make a url work for any combination of directory prefixes or a subsite in a folder, etc .... to much of a pain to deal with.

Comment: i tried but it doesnt work. if i nav into the events dir, and then click on, i end with events/archive/etc. which doesn't exist.

Comment: Correction!, no you are right, sorry. i was forgetting the first /.

Comment: i'm so focused on the Drupal, and it' advanced features i am forgetting basic HTML!!!, embarassed,<br> thank you